How do I generate Simplex noise with a bias on lower values?
I want to generate Simplex noise with a "bias" on lower values. The project I am using this for is intended to generate islands, but the islands are too close together and sometimes connect in ways I dislike. I would like to spread them farther apart and generate fewer islands, without sacrificing the smoothness of Simplex/Perlin noise. How can I do this?

I think this is way too broad for SO.  But in general you either do exactly what you say -- bias the simplex noise so that it produces lower values (like, subtract 0.75 from all of the noise so you get values in the range -1.75 to 0.25).  Or you apply a function to the result, which will also lower the values.  exp() is popular because it makes relatively smooth interpolation.

By using Math.exp() 3 times consecutively, I got a result I think I can work with. Thank you!
